# iOS 10 App Not Showing in Settings

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode8, ios10

I recently developed an iOS app using Xcode 8 beta. I ran it on my iPhone (which is currently operating on iOS 10 beta), and it worked fine.

However, my app uses the camera, and I have been attempting to have the user go to settings, and enable the camera.

But my app does not appear in the list of apps in settings. It does not show up in the developer section either.

How can  I resolve this bug? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try closing the settings app and reopening it?  Sometimes with custom settings you need to reload the settings app.

Comment: @JAL I just tried that. Unfortunately it did not work. ☹️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from iOS 10, **it's mandatory to add "NSCameraUsageDescription"** in info.plist which is just an informatory message to the user stating the reason for accessing camera. It will be presented to the user while trying to access the camera only for the first time after installing the application.

Though this key is existing since iOS 7, it has been made mandatory in iOS 10 beta. Please refer to below Apple reference link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW15

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the debug log is helpful! I ended up adding the following to my info.plist:

```
NSCameraUsageDescription
```

Then in the right side, I described how the app uses the camera.